# Encode unicode list with integers and strings to UTF-8 / compare two strings

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have to scrape meal data from a dining webpage with Python and Beautifulsoup.
I store the individual meals in one table and combine the data in a second menu table (menuID, mealID, time, etc.). 
To prevent duplicates in the meal table, I pull all meals with (assigned) IDs in one list and run the meal name from the webpage against this list.

The unicode list from MySQL looks like this:
[(410, u'Oatmeal'), (411, u'White Rice'), (412, u'Sliced Potatoes with Onions'), (413, u'Orange French Toast'),(414, u'Saut\xe9ed Mushrooms')]

My problem: the data from the webpage comes as utf-8 strings with the consequence that it is comparing "Sautéed Mushrooms" with "Saut\xe9ed Mushrooms" and therefore adding it to the database because they are different.

The whole charset thing is quite new to me and I spent several hours to figure out how to convert either a list to UTF-8 or converting the webpage string to unicode so that the comparison runs through.

Anyone any idea how I could do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the data before comparing it with the MySQL values:

Suppose you get "Sautéed Mushrooms" from webpage, you need to compare:

```
str = "Sautéed Mushrooms"
if str.decode('utf-8','ignore') == 'values from list':
    #your code
```